# flutter 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flutter

I got interested in flutter and went ahead to install as per the guide on the website and go this error during running it on CMD

```
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

That's really weird since Flutter doesn't use MySql in any way.
My `git` runs fine with no problems and also `node` is fine.
I have seen the issue filed with no answer. [GITHUB](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17907)

If you have fixed this issue please post your answer.

Comment: I uninstalled MySQL and it worked fine after that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Zip provided on [flutter.io](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#get-the-flutter-sdk) gave me a problem. To avoid this error, I had to use the GitHub repository following the following procedure.

1. Go to C:\ Drive and create a folder called flutter.
2. Go to that folder and start git bash
3. Type `git clone -b beta https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` and enter
4. After its complete, add the path `C:\flutter\flutter\bin` in environment variables
5. Finally, start CMD and type flutter doctor and the error is disappeared

---

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to escape the ampersand with a caret (^), it will look like ^&. Go to System variable path remove or edit:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5\;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.4 ^& MySQL Utilities 1.5.4 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;
```

Comment: I just deleted these references as MySql was uninstalled, and resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Removing from system variable Path ***C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;*** and ***C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;***